# CouchDB view throwing invalid UTF-8 JSON error when using key, startkey

Tags: json, curl, couchdb

I have a VERY basic view defined in CouchDB:

```
function(doc) {
  if(doc.date && doc.erc) {
    emit(doc.date, doc.erc);
  }
}
```

It simply pulls ALL documents and sorts by dates.

I've tried appending

```
?startkey="2010-05-01"
```

to the URL and Futon just browser redirects.

I've tried using CURL as well:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:5984/plots/_design/by_date/_view/by_date?startkey="2010-05-01"
```

That throws an error:

```
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid UTF-8 JSON"}
```

What am I doing wrong? This should be a VERY basic thing.

Thanks,
-Jim

Answer (score 33, accepted):

CouchDB needs to see the double-quotes.

Bash is probably eating your double quotes before `curl` runs. Put the URL (double-quotes and all) in single quotes.

```
curl -X GET 'http://localhost:5984/plots/_design/by_date/_view/by_date?startkey="2010-05-01"'
```

That way, Bash will send the quotes to `curl` which will send them to CouchDB.

Possibly Firefox or Futon is eating your quotes too. Futon has a gray pointer icon in the upper-right. That links to the raw URL of the view. Try adding the `startkey` there. You can also input the double-quotes as `%22`.

Comment: YES! That works for CURL. Any idea why appending that to the URL while using Firefox/Futon seems to trip it up?

Comment: Updated with ideas about Firefox

Comment: `... Bash is probably eating your double quotes before curl runs ...` that was true in my case. On my terminal command line the curl command was not working. Then I used back-slash before my double-quotes and the problem got resolved. Also I needed to use back-slash before `&` character, too. Like this: `?startkey=\"ב\"\&endkey=\"ש\"`

Comment: HOURS on a similar problem. When forming the URL to make a request to my update handler, the key must be in quotes, but not the value. Version 2.2.0. Method: 'PUT'. URL: 'testdata/_design/testDesigns/_update/setKeyValue/DOCID?key="hairColor"&value=purple' . If I put quotes around the value, they get carried over as escaped quotes in the database.

Answer (score 5):

I dont know whether you have already got the solution.. anyway for viewers like me who got the same error. This is the solution . I tried in windows

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:5984/plots/_design/by_date/_view/by_date?startkey=\"2010-05-01\"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
curl xxx:xxxm@aaaa:5984/kitsi_arin/_design/arinDesign/_view/TestView2?key=\"Arindam\"
```

This works for me in cygwin

Answer (score 0):

You can also use URL `%codes`, `%22` gets converted to double quotes `"` by most fetch programs

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:5984/plots/_design/by_date/_view/by_date?startkey=%222010-05-01%22
```